# Electric field of a line charge, along itself

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

look at the pic :
[image]

What is the electric field in along the line of charge with charge density $\lambda$ and length $L$. Is the electric field zero along the line without any difference in height?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the line of charge as a collection of (very many) point charges of the same sign.  Outside of the charge distribution but colinear with it, each point charge will have an electric field which points in the same direction (away from the distribution if the charges are positive, and toward the distribution if the charges are negative).  These will all interfere constructively, meaning the electric field will not vanish.

One could actually apply a similar argument to show the electric field is nonzero at all points outside the charge distribution (though it's slightly nontrivial to argue about the direction of the field at an arbitrary point).

**Edit**:  I was considering a constant charge density, but all of this should work as long as the entire charge distribution has the same sign.